# How to move mouse cursor to fire event Focus lost for any user control in code?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

For exmaple, when cursor on a textbox, I want to code can move the cursor to somewhere so that focuslost event can be fired in code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to programatically move the mouse cursor using Silverlight? This is not possible. What is the goal you are trying to achieve? Moving the user's mouse cursor around via code is almost certainly not the best approach (even if it was possible).